# Absolute div being cut off

Tags: html, css, tooltip

We use tooltips, to display color names on a color picker.

<s>**You can see the result here:** [www.printnil.com](http://printnil.com/products/angebotsmappe?variant=1052118699)</s>

Unfortunately the tooltips gets cut off on the left and right side.

**css from the color picker**

```
 .swatch {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding-top: 55px;
  top: -55px;
  margin-bottom: -55px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the swatch div a `position: relative`, a height large enough to fit the control and tool tip, and offsets  `top: -45px` and `margin-bottom: -45px`. Like so:

```
.swatch {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-top: 45px;
    top: -45px;
    margin-bottom: -45px;
}
```

should fix it.

Comment: We implement your answer and it works pretty good – The tooltip still gets cut on the left or right side, if you pick a color that is near the edge. But that is probably not fixable.

Comment: You could expand the `width` and add a negative `margin-right` (similar to above) to include the tooltip that's getting cut off on the right.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the question to a cut off on the left and right side.